# Using specific heat at different conditions

Tags: thermodynamics

Why can the change in energy of an ideal gas system (through a process in which V is not constant), still be calculated using Cv? (as in DE=Cv*DT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscripts v and p refer to how these heat capacities **are measured** experimentally, not how they are applied in practice.  In each case, the heat capacity can be measured by determining how much heat has to be added to the system in either a constant volume experiment or in a constant pressure experiment.  On the other hand, for an ideal gas, irrespective of whether the experiment is carried out at constant pressure or at constant volume, the changes in internal energy and enthalpy are given by dU=CvdT and dH=CpdT.  This is because U and H are functions only of T for an ideal gas.  The general mathematical definitions of these heat capacities are $$C_v=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_v$$$$C_p=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_p$$If you are not dealing with an ideal gas, then the volume or the pressure also affect U and H, and this must be accounted for.  But, for an ideal gas, only the temperature change is required to determine the changes in U and H.

Comment: Great job understanding the question

Comment: @Chester Miller thanks. This might be more math related but when you integrate Cv with respect to T you treat V as a constant (which is the opposite of the partial derivative that defines Cv), but what if throughout the experiment V was not constant?  Can you still treat it as a constant during the integration and why (since it during the experiment it changed)?

Comment: (since it did change during the experiment)*

Comment: If it is an ideal gas, then it doesn't matter if the volume changed, since the internal energy is a function only of temperature.  U is a function of state, so you could evaluate its change by following an alternate path in which you first held the volume constant and increased the temperature, and then, in a second step, held the temperature constant and changed the volume.  For the second step, the change in internal energy of the ideal gas would be zero.  So irrespective of whether you followed the actual path or the alternate path, the change in internal energy would be the same.

Comment: Ah that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for this clarification.